# MySQL - WHERE/AND with pivot table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

**CLINICS**

```
id | name | description | lat | lng | opening_hours| logo | address | city | zip | phone_number | email | url | gmaps_link | marker | created_at | updated_at
```

**SERVICES**

```
id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

**CLINIC_SERVICES**

```
clinic_id | service_id
```

This query should return two results, but at the moment it is returning 0:

```
SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT clinics.id as cid, clinics.lat, clinics.lng, clinics.opening_hours,
        clinics.logo, clinics.address, clinics.city, clinics.name, clinics.description,
        clinics.zip, clinics.phone_number, clinics.email, clinics.url, clinics.gmaps_link,
        clinics.marker,
        countries.full_name AS country,
        (6378 * acos(
            cos(radians(-33.84801)) * cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(lng) - radians(151.06488)) +
            sin(radians(-33.84801)) * sin(radians(lat))))
        AS distance
        FROM clinics
        JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
        LEFT JOIN clinics_services ON clinics.id = clinics_services.clinic_id
         WHERE clinics_services.service_id = 1 AND clinics_services.service_id = 29
        GROUP BY clinics.id
        ) AS distances
    WHERE distance < 50000
    ORDER BY distance ASC
```

If I put **OR** instead of **AND** I am getting 5 clinics, which actually works as I think should work. How can I get proper result (clinic have both services)? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post sample data.

Comment: Have you check the supposed answer? Is the issue still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

According to [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647944/mysql-group-by-having-different-values-same-field) this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT clinics.id as cid, clinics.lat, clinics.lng, clinics.opening_hours,
        clinics.logo, clinics.address, clinics.city, clinics.name, clinics.description,
        clinics.zip, clinics.phone_number, clinics.email, clinics.url, clinics.gmaps_link,
        clinics.marker,
        countries.full_name AS country,
        (6378 * acos(
            cos(radians(-33.84801)) * cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(lng) - radians(151.06488)) +
            sin(radians(-33.84801)) * sin(radians(lat))))
        AS distance
        FROM clinics
        JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
        LEFT JOIN clinics_services ON clinics.id = clinics_services.clinic_id
         WHERE clinics_services.service_id = 1 OR clinics_services.service_id = 29
        GROUP BY clinics.id
        HAVING SUM(clinics_services.service_id = 1) > 0 AND SUM(clinics_services.service_id = 29) > 0
        ) AS distances
    WHERE distance < 50000
    ORDER BY distance ASC
```